# How to show $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}E(\mathbb{1}_{\{|Z-z|\leq \epsilon\}}\mid X) = E(\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \mathbb{1}_{\{|Z-z|\leq \epsilon\}}\mid X)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am wondering how I can show that:

$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}E\left(\mathbb{1}_{\{|Z-z|\leq \epsilon\}}\mid X\right) = E\left(\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \mathbb{1}_{\{|Z-z|\leq \epsilon\}}\mid X\right)
$$

My approach is to define a subset of the above sequence in terms of $\{|Z-z|\leq \frac{1}{n}\}$, so that I can use the dominated convergence theorem. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Isn't the assertion a direct consequence of the dominated convergence theorem? Are you worried because the limit is not along a countable sequence?

Comment: The dominated convergence theorem is stated for $n \to \infinity$, but here it is going to a point value, $0^+$. How can we use the DCT if the limit is not going to infinity?